# Execute and save changes to same file once file open

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to activate / open embedded excel in word once open the file manually. Once the excel content shown, want to save the changes to **same document**. But, `ActiveDocument.Save` in this code not saving the changes.

```
Sub Document_Open()
 activateObject
 'MsgBox "activating excel object"
End Sub
Sub activateObject()
  With ActiveDocument
  Set oShape = .InlineShapes(1) 'The embedded object is the first InlineShape.
  'Set oShape = .Shapes(1) 'The embedded object is the first Shape.
  Set oOLEFormat = oShape.OLEFormat
  oOLEFormat.Open
  ActiveDocument.Save  
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Opening the embedded excel does not stop the code execution, so once the file is opened the save occurs immediately before changes are made

Comment: so, how to save changes after Opening the embedded excel?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you want the user to work with the Worksheet, then when they finish editing and click outside it, you want the document to be saved, I think you could do something like the following using Word Events and a timer loop.

If that isn't what you're trying to achieve, please modify your question.

Insert a new Class Module, name it `WordAppEventHandler`, and copy the following code into it:

```
Public WithEvents wd As Word.Application
Private m_FullName As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
m_FullName = ""
End Sub

Private Sub wd_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
Dim AlertTime As Date
If m_FullName = "" Then
  m_FullName = Sel.Application.ActiveDocument.FullName
Else
  If (Sel.Application.ActiveDocument.FullName = m_FullName) Then
    DoEvents
    Sel.Document.Save
    ' Not sure you really need to do this teardown as Word may do it
    ' automatically, but playing safe.
    AlertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime AlertTime, "TearDownMacro"
  Else
    ' you would get here if the user clicked in another Word document, for example.
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

Modify your existing code to look something like this:

```
Dim wdeh As New WordAppEventHandler

Sub Document_Open()
Dim AlertTime As Date
AlertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime AlertTime, "OpenMacro"
activateObject
End Sub
Sub OpenMacro()
activateObject
 'MsgBox "activating excel object"
End Sub
Sub activateObject()
Dim AlertTime As Date
Dim oOLEformat As Word.OLEFormat
Dim oShape As Word.InlineShape
Set wdeh.wd = Application
With ActiveDocument
  Set oShape = .InlineShapes(1) 'The embedded object is the first InlineShape.
  'Set oShape = .Shapes(1) 'The embedded object is the first Shape.
  Set oOLEformat = oShape.OLEFormat
  oOLEformat.Open
End With
End Sub

Sub TearDownMacro()
Set wdeh.wd = Nothing
Set wdeh = Nothing
End Sub


Public Sub EventMacro()
' Just wait another second.
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this code. could not save the changes. Thank you.

Comment: @Premlatha - yes, my bad, as I was starting Document_Open manually during testing. Fail! So I've posted some new code. I'm now using .OnTime to break out of that and have abandoned the Timer loop as it wasn't actually doing what I thought anyway. However, this now relies on the WindowChange event to behave in the way it behaves on my test system. Just can't think of a way to improve it right now.